# Ionic emulate Ios fails to run The session does not open my app

Tags: ionic-framework

Ionic emulate ios failed on Mac OS Yosemite. Their have some cases were the ios device emulated, but shortly after the terminal console shoots up the error message below.

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (code=146):
Invalid device state
An error was encountered processing the command (code=146):
Exception encountered connecting to CoreSimulatorBridge: Unable to connect to CoreSimulatorBridge
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/yay/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/2CAA2C39-7F22-4AF2-BBDE-86609188F37C/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/yay/code/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/myApp.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/yay/code/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/yay/code/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/yay/code/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Someone please help!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is because you used sudo to create and/or build the project.

Just input these commands (without the `$` of course):

1) Remove with sudo

```
$ sudo ionic platform remove ios
```

2) Add iOS back without sudo

```
$ ionic platform add ios
```

3) Run iOS emulator

```
$ ionic emulate ios
```

Source: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4052 (rajkotecha's comment)

Comment: I had to do an additional step, because some files were created as root:
sudo chown [USERNAME] /Users/[USERNAME]/.config/configstore/*

Answer (score 1):

**Do NOT** use sudo when creating or building the project.

Please see https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4052

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered this issue before, and I believe you messed up with your permission. However, I managed to solve it by reinstall everything from scratch (NOT reformat OS). I suggest you may try to remove all your Xcode, ionic, cordova, and ios-sim content and reinstall again.

1. Delete your Xcode from your Mac OS.
2. Remove everything inside:

   - ***/usr/local/bin***
   - ***/usr/local/include***
   - ***/usr/local/lib/dtrace***
   - ***/usr/local/share/man/man1***
   - ***/usr/local/share/systemtap/tapset/***
3. Delete the folder:

   - ***/usr/local/lib/node_modules***

Once you done the instruction above, kindly use your spotlight to search for keywords such as **node**, **cordova**, **ionic**, etc... to see whether it is still exist or not. Please also ensure **yourApp** within your ***Users/username*** folder is **deleted**.

You may also try to use your terminal input:

```
npm -v
cordova -v
ionic -v
```

It will shows nothing/not found if you've deleted everything completely.

Now you can download and install Xcode from App Store, and wait for Xcode is fully installed in your Mac, then proceed to [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) to start again your ionic project.

Lastly, once you begin to create an ionic project, by right you no need to use any ***sudo*** commands anymore in creating or building this project.

Example:

```
ionic build ios
```

Instead of:

```
sudo ionic build ios
```

It should be working unless you are not the root user.

Happy coding and have a nice day! :D

Comment: Do the files in /usr/local/bin just recreate them selves? I going to need a bit more explanation on that command before I do it.

Comment: Yes, it will. Ive done this and all my files in /usr/local/bin have recovered as previous.